# macOS addPersistentStoreWithType causing "could not be autosaved" error

Tags: macos, document

When I save NSPersistentDocument to iCloud using addPersistentStoreWithType and migratePersistentStore, addPersistentStoreWithType is causing "The document APP_NAME could not be autosaved. The file has been changed by another application." Error. I have autosave turned on for my NSPersistentDocument subclass.

I can run the same code over and over, and if I have addPersistentStoreWithType code it displays a few seconds later "The document APP_NAME could not be autosaved. The file has been changed by another application." If I comment this code out, the error doesn't occur.

Why would calling addPersistentStoreWithType cause The document could not be autosaved error? Before I updated my Mac to High Sierra Version 10.13.4, this did not happen. Before I could blame all of this to Apple, can anyone confirm my findings?

```
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *migrationPSC = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self getAManagedObjectModel]];

    id sourceStore = [migrationPSC addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:NULL URL:localUrl options:nil error:&error];//this code causes the error.
```